# Vertx js and Redis Sentinel Connectivity

Tags: redis, vert.x, redis-sentinel, vertx-verticle

Am Working on the versions of Vertx 3.5.0 Version and Redis with master and Slave Architecture .In their Official Site they have didn't mention of their redis sentinel Support.

So can i create a jar file which gets the Master Details of Redis and use that jar file in Vertx-js Program to get the Master Details and make the Connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

3.5.0 does contain basic support for Redis Sentinel but was not properly documented. It is now updated to be polyglot and there is a small reference to it on the new docs:

https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-redis-client/blob/master/src/main/asciidoc/java/index.adoc#redis-sentinel

This should be available on 3.5.1 but you can already use it on 3.5.0 as the only missing parts were polyglot generation and the docs themselves.